# Subsonic MVC Template and Code Generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3

I am using Subsonic MVC Template from [this project](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/subsonicproject/SubSonic%20MVC%20Template.zip).

Here is a folder named [Code Template] which contains the .tt files for generating views and controllers. But that is giving me error
"MvcTextTemplateHost not found"

I want to generate the create/edit/list pages based on the tables generated by subsonic. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is this:

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/downloads

1 add subsonic dll to bin folder
2 add reference to that DLL

3 add a connection string to your web.config or app.config

add the connection string name to your ttinclude file

drag files into your models folder

you are then ready to go

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo

brilliant up and running in like 10 mins

Comment: Its for generating the DAL. I want to generate the Create/Edit/Details page based on that DAL automatically. I think it was subsonic scaffolding in 2.* releases.

Comment: oh just copy the folder CodeTemplates from visual studio install folder / common 7/IDE/itemtemplates/csharp/web/mvc 2/   vthen on properties remove the text in Custom Tool, then you can set these how you like and it will create your views etc how you want them to look, but by default you can create a strongly typed view from the subsonic class and this will do all the mapping automatically for you  if that helps !!!!